# Fedora 33 polkit ignoring org.freedesktop.login1.reboot rules

Tags: linux, fedora, policykit

I have set the following Polkit rule to prevent users from rebooting my Fedora 33 machine using Gnome:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {

    if ( ( action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.reboot" ) ||
         ( action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-ignore-inhibit" ) ||
         ( action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-multiple-sessions" ) ||
         ( action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.set-reboot-parameter" ) ||
         ( action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.set-reboot-to-boot-loader-entry " ) ||
         ( action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.set-reboot-to-boot-loader-menu" ) ||
         ( action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.set-reboot-to-firmware-setup" ) ) {

        return polkit.Result.AUTH_ADMIN;

    }
});
```

But something is not working as it should be because users still can reboot the machine. Does anyone knows what could be happening?

Edit: I have tried the "*.power-off" actions and they get ignored too...

Edit2: "*.suspend" works as expected but neither "*.power-off" nor "*.reboot" looks to work even if if I try to trigger these rules with pkcheck.

Comment: Are other commands such as `pkcheck` or `systemctl reboot`, also unaffected by the changes?

Comment: If I replace reboot by suspend and run `pkcheck --action-id  org.freedesktop.login1.suspend --process $(pidof gnome-session-ctl) -u` I get:

`
polkit\56retains_authorization_after_challenge=1
Not authorized.
`

However for "reboot" I don't get anything.... so I suppose that rule is not triggering...